# supervisor for an executable in linux

Tags: c++, linux, monitor

I am currently developing an executable which runs on linux. I want to have a supervisor which monitor this executable and restart which it is killed. Is there any command for doing so? or suggest me some way to do it

Note: the code is in c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This supervisor already exists and is always running.  It's called `init`, and most versions are controlled by the entries in `/etc/inittab`.

Answer (score 1):

[Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) comes with most linux distributions and can do what you're looking for, plus a fair amount more, like checking memory, disk space, connectivity,...

From the [docs](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#existence_testing)  you could have something like so in your monit config file:

```
check file with path /cifs/mydata
  if does not exist for 5 cycles then exec "/usr/bin/mount_cifs.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is just to spawn the process yourself, wait for it to exit, and then restart it.  The simplest way to do that is just in a shell script loop.  Generally, though, this kind of watchdog architecture tends to be fragile and glitchy.  Why is your process dying?  What happens while it's restarting?  Is there state preserved elsewhere in the system that assumes that the current "version" of your process is the same as it was at some time in the past?

Generally, this just isn't done.  It's almost always best to either architect your process as a one-off that handles one event/command/request, or write it robustly such that it can be presumed to always be alive.  And if you can't make that work, just wrap it in a shell loop.

Comment: If the watchdog concept is so bad, why does every Linux instance use it?

Comment: Virtually nothing in linux is watchdogged.  Certainly critical services like httpd, mysqld, etc... are not in typical installations.  Core stuff like dbus-daemon ditto.  You have a counterexample?

Comment: Many small pieces of the system are not individually subject to process monitoring and automatic restart, but the whole user-mode system itself is.  On pretty much any linux distro you care to name, this is the ONLY function of process 1, the one process that every linux system must have.  And specifically your terminal login process is monitored and restarted should it ever exit.

Comment: If you want to explain characteristics of processes monitored by `init`, and use that as a basis for claiming it's probably a poor choice for the OP's problem, fine.  But making blanket statements that it's "fragile and glitchy" just suggests you don't know Linux.

Comment: Um... chill.  I'm just saying that explicitly writing an application that **expects** to be watchdogged is questionable design, and counter to the existing paradigms of the system.  And FWIW: you're basically wrong about init.  Neither sysvinit, upstart, nor systemd do any significant watchdogging of processes in modern linux distros (though systemd has done a really good job of turning many things into launch-on-demand services, which has some of the same properties).  Just try it: kill -9 something important and see if it restarts.

Comment: While you can control restarting based on the presence or absence of the `respawn` keyword in the configuration, sysvinit basically does nothing except spawn processes when it receives signals, either `SIGCHLD` or a new runlevel.  Other variants like upstart add more features, but continue this basic behavior.